# How to enable SharedArrayBuffer in CoreWebView2?

Tags: cors, webassembly, webview2, sharedarraybuffer

I am using CoreWebView2 to bring a webapp onto the windows desktop. The webapp uses a webassembly module that relies on SharedArrayBuffers. I can enable SharedArrayBuffer with the correct setting of Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy in the webapp.
How can I do the same for CoreWebView2? I get the error SharedArrayBuffer not defined when I open the debug console.

Neiter the access kind settings  (COREWEBVIEW2_HOST_RESOURCE_ACCESS_KIND_DENY_CORS, etc) nor the environment setting --disable-web-security seems to have an effect. I am using WebView2 2.1.0.1777-prerelease on Visual Studo 2022.